# Set "table" in spark session

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In some spark/scala code (I cannot link the source) I see a dataframe being created like this:

```
val someDataFrame = spark.table("dataframeName")
```

where spark is a `SparkSession`. How can I set a table in the spark session? i.e. if I have a frame like this:

```
 val salaryData = Seq(("James", "Sales", 3000),
    ("Michael", "Sales", 4600),
    ("Robert", "Sales", 4100),
    ("Maria", "Finance", 3000),
    ("James", "Sales", 3000),
  )
  val salaryData = simpleData.toDF("employee_name", "department", "salary")
```

how can I set `salaryData` as a table in a `SparkSession` and fetch it like this:

```
val salaryDataframeFromSession = spark.table("salaries")
```

Comment: I think that function is used to read tables from Hive, to replace `spark.sql("select * from MyTable")`. You could create some temp view with `createOrReplaceTempView` to use that function I think

Comment: you need to save the dataframe with `salaryData.save(...)` first and then to be able to load it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this via

```
salaryData.createOrReplaceTempView("salaries")
```